# Accessing .net Core API via azure VM throws ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: linux, azure, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, ubuntu-server

I've set up a linux VM using Azure and I have the public IP from that machine.

I've cloned my repo inside that machine and I run `dotnet run` and I get the output:

```sh
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /home/g67Admin/projeto_integrador_grupo67/mdv
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Then I try to go to: `https://(public IP):5001/api/Drivers` and I cannot access it, gives me this error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I've went to the azure portal and tried to authorize the ports 5000 and 5001 from any source to any source, rebooted the machine multiple times and still get connection refused.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your local development server won't listen on your public IP or allow traffic from any other machine in your network. It only listens on `localhost`. You need to explicitly bind other urls to your server.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core

You can run your code like this:

> dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:5001

Or you can use `Use WebHost.UseUrls()` to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Ok it solved, only problem now regards the communication between VM and Database

Comment: Glad I could help. If your question was answered by this, you should accept it by clicking the check mark. This way, we can help keep the focus on questions which still have no answer. The communication between VM and database should probably be a second question.